# Protractor (node:9208) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ElementNotVisibleError: element not interactable. But still working intermittently

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor, webdriverwait

I am trying to click an element using protractor but getting below exception

```
(node:9208) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ElementNotVisibleError: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=69.0.3497.92)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591088 (7b2b2dca23cca0862f674758c9a3933e685c27d5),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (........\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:546:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (........\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:509:13)
    at doSend.then.response (........\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:441:30)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)Error
    at ElementArrayFinder.applyAction_ (........\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:459:27)
    at ElementArrayFinder.(anonymous function).args [as click] (........\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:91:29)
    at ElementFinder.(anonymous function).args [as click] (........\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:831:22)
    at selenMethods.clickElement (........\folders\utils\SelenMethods.js:49:26)
    at ........\folders\pages\homePage.js:28:29
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Below is the HTML Snippet

```
<a href="#inviteUser" id="menuBtnAdduser" class="list-group-item list-group-child-item close-menu-item list-item-heading ng-scope" translate="templates.usersTable.addUser" xpath="1"><span class="ng-scope">Invite new user</span></a>
```

Below is the protractor code to click the element

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(elemen), 4000);
element(by.xpath("//a[@id='menuBtnAdduser']/span[contains(text(),'Invite new user')]"));
```

Comment: Hi @sriam, did you try to click on the link directly not the span. Also i see you are waiting for an element, but is it the one that you post? Try with waitForElementToBeVIsible() could help.

Comment: Element is visible and I was able to highlight it as well. But the error says the element is not interactable.

Comment: Hi @siram, try to click on the link directly: element(by.xpath("//a[@id='menuBtnAdduser']")

Comment: I tried and it is working once in a while, the error says the "element not interactable" and there is very less documentation available for that...

Answer (score 0):

To click on the desired element you can use the following solution:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(elemen), 4000);
element(by.xpath("//a[@class='list-group-item list-group-child-item close-menu-item list-item-heading ng-scope' and @id='menuBtnAdduser']/span[@class='ng-scope' and contains(.,'Invite new user')]"));
```

Comment: Hi Debanjan, thanku for the response. There is no problem with the xpath. I was able to find the element and highlight it in multiple ways but protractor fails with an error element is not interactable.

Comment: @sriramnarayana: I am facing the same issue. Did you solve yours?

Answer (score 0):

Try to click using Href:

```
 element(by.cssContainingText('[href*="#inviteUser"]', 'Invite new user'))
```